# How to build a programmable sticky button

Tags: arduino, solenoid, button

I'm trying to build a button that can exist in two modes. Either it springs back after being pressed, or it stays pressed. I want to switch between these two modes using some complex logic, controlled by an Arduino or a RaspberryPi. The dimensions should be around 1'-by-1', and I'll have a 5-by-6 grid of these buttons to make a puzzle. I'm struggling to come up with a simple design for one such button.

I thought of using a solenoid, but they have a duty cycle and use a lot of power in one of the two modes. Ideally, I would only need power to switch between the two states. That way, a player can play with the puzzle for a while, then leave it alone overnight and come back to playing the day after. I'd rather not keep the solenoids powered overnight.

Another idea I had was to use two electromagnets to pull some kind of a latch back and forth, to jam the button in its pressed state. But that seems complicated and finicky.

Comment: i think that this may be an XY problem ... you are asking for help with what you consider to be a solution to an unspecified problem, even though the solution may be misguided .... what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @jsotola what part of "I want to have the button stay pushed in sometimes" is unspecified?

Comment: @jstola That's fair -- perhaps there is a solution I'm not considering. Jasen's idea with a circuit breaker is progress. I want a button that behaves similarly to a kitchen circuit breaker that can be reset by pressing in a button.

Comment: @Passerby, this is the thing ... some people will say `i want the button to stay pushed` when they mean `i want the light to stay on when i release the button`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are solenoids that can pull in instead of push out. Ones with springs on them so that they default to out.

Taking one of these, and you can build a simple latch. When the button is pressed down, the solenoid arm is pushed into a hole on the side of the button, locking it in place. You can then just pulse the solenoid to unlatch and the button pops back up. So no need to power it all the time. For this you would need to fabricate a button cover and spring setup (hello 3d printers). Or you could modify an arcade button type switch with a drill. How you do it would depend on the solenoid you use.

Alternatively you could make it electronic. Instead of keeping the switch pressed in physically, have it light up an led. You could get button switches with LEDs built in that you can control. This would mean you need to power it, but it will be much less current than a solenoid.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. The button locks by default, and I pulse a solenoid to unlock it. I can send that pulse any time I find the button pressed while it shouldn't be. Time for some tiny solenoid shopping.

Answer (score 4):

Someone has already invented this.

The [circuit breakers](https://www.simkits.com/product/circuit-breaker-for-flight-simulation/) used to simulate aircraft breakers in flight simulators can be released by a small current, but they are not cheap.

[image: image from simkits]

The device pictured sells for hundreds of dollars. I see a relay mechanism used like a [firearm sear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sear_(firearm)), some contacts, and a spring-loaded plunger - you may be able to duplicate this at a lower cost

Comment: With 3d printing this could be done for much much cheaper.

Comment: Thanks. The picture gives me some ideas.

Comment: yeah, I was suprised how informative the picture was,

Comment: you'll probably still need to transistors to drive the coils

Comment: @Passerby or it could be done with profile-cut polycarbonate sheet, probably cheaper

Comment: Although mechanics _is_ expensive, I'm sure the price is determined more from the low volume and the overflowing bundles of dollar bills in the pockets of the typical flight simulator enthusiast, rather than by the complexity of the construction.

Comment: it;s a part for pilot training machines, nof so much for hobby virtual fliers, until recetly airlines had lots of money.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a small servo could be used to pull down the push button stem.

[image]

Comment: That's cool, but wouldn't that require my finger to force the servo to spin when I press the button? I have a few VEX servos, and they are tough to spin with my fingers when un-powered. When powered, that's even tougher and likely a bad idea to try to force them. Or do you mean that the servo's arm quickly slams into the hole once the button touches the switch? Also, 30 servos are significantly more expensive than 30 solenoids.

Comment: it is just a rough drawing ... the slot in the button stem should have been drawn taller, so that the button stem would not touch the servo arm before the switch activates

Answer (score 4):

You can use a permanent magnet strong enough to hold the button down, but not strong enough to pull it down.  Put an electromagnet in series with it in the magnetic circuit, so that a pulse on the electromagnet will counteract the permanent magnet and let the button come up.

I guess the easiest way to arrange this would probably be to attach a permanent magnet to the bottom of solenoid, so that if you push the solenoid in, then the magnet will hold it down, but you can energize the solenoid to release it.

Comment: I like that. Fewer mechanical parts.